# would clutter my wallet?

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

My little son brought me an old ten-dinar bill and suggested I put in my wallet. I told it him it is no good anymore and thought I'd say:

> it'd just clutter my wallet.

Is the expression is natural English?
If not, how would you say it?

Comment: It is OK. You might reword slightly as *"it'd just be (more) clutter in my wallet"* or *"it'd just clutter up my wallet"*

Answer (score 3):

I like it.

As an alternative, the first thing that came to my mind was

> It'd just take up space.

This implies that the bill would unnecessarily take up space and serve no meaningful purpose.